# Prove the identity $\sum_{{{\underset{k-even}{k=0}}}}^{n}{n \choose k}2^{k}=\frac{3^{n}+(-1)^{n}}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I need to prove the following identity:

$\sum_{{{\underset{k-even}{k=0}}}}^{n}{n \choose k}2^{k}=\frac{3^{n}+(-1)^{n}}{2}$

I know that -

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}2^{k}=3^{n}$

but don't know how to continue.

Comment: Look also at $(1+(-2))^n$.

Answer (score 3):

The idea here is that of *polarization*: applying actions to an expression in such a way that the right parts of it exhibit the right constructive or destructive interference when superposed. This is a very general yet simple technique that is surprisingly heavily involved in math (at the moment I am thinking of harmonic analysis and representation theory). The flip side of this technique is using twisting and averaging tricks to project onto special parts of spaces.

For example, all functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ may be decomposed into a sum of an *even* function and an *odd* function. In order to annihilate the even part, you would take the difference $f(x)-f(-x)$. It is easy to check that $f(x)-f(-x)$ is odd, and then by subtracting the odd part from the original function one obtains the symmetric function $f(x)+f(-x)$. Then, normalizing, we have

$$f(x)=\overbrace{\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}}^{\rm even}+\overbrace{\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}}^{\rm odd}.$$

Consider applying this to polynomials. What is the even part of a polynomial? Now notice that the expression is the even part of the polynomial $(1+x)^n$, via the Binomial theoerm, at $x=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by the Binomial Theorem, we can say for any $x$ that $$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k.$$ Consider in particular $x=\pm2.$